# CompareTo method not working as expected for my address book

Tags: java, arraylist, string-comparison

```
public void compareTo(String lname1, String lname2) {      
/*  Note to self: Using this method is case sensitive, because 
    it only prints if names are found in the array. And those names 
    are case sensitive inside the array, even though I'm using the 
    CompareTo method from java's String
    class which is NOT inherently case sensitive.   ???????? */


boolean foundContact = false;


for(int i = 0;  i < arrayOfPersons.size(); i++){
        if(arrayOfPersons.get(i).getFname().equals(lname1) && (arrayOfPersons.get(i).getFname().equals(lname2))) {
            lname1.compareTo(lname2);
            foundContact = true; 
         }
     }


if (foundContact == false)
    System.out.println("This option is case sensitive. Check your spelling and try again. Otherwise these contacts do not exist.");

if(lname1.compareTo(lname2) < 0)
    System.out.println(lname1 + " comes after " + lname2 + " .");

if(lname1.compareTo(lname2) == 0)
    System.out.println(lname1 + " are equal " + lname2 + ".");

if(lname1.compareTo(lname2) > 0)
    System.out.println(lname1 + " comes before " + lname2 + " .");

}

case 6: 
    System.out.println("Enter last name #1:");
    String lname3 = scnr.next();
    System.out.println("Enter last name #2:");
    String lname4 = scnr.next();
    Necronomicon.compareTo(lname3, lname4);
    break;

// This case is from my main and shows how I use the compareTo method. Just one of many options to my address book.
```

I created an address book. One of the requirements for my address book is to compare two people by last name. This is the method I wrote to accomplish that goal. However, it's case sensitive when used, so I tried writing a warning to the user.

But the warning prints regardless of whether the contacts are found in the `arrayOfPersons`. So I think that my boolean is not updating correctly or the way I'm checking to see if the two names exist in the persons array is wrong? Is that right?

Comment: What is the relationship of `compareTo` to your problem?  It doesn't look like `compareTo` has anything to do with it; it's just the `for` loop and your `if` conditions.

Comment: You can use compareToIgnoreCase() if you want to ignore the case. But I am not able to figure what you are looking for.

Comment: The method is being called in my main. I created a menu which gives a user an option to compare two users they already have in their address book. (In theory) So I have the user enter two last names they'd like to compare, store those strings in variables and use them as arguments in the method.

Comment: Can you show us how arrayofPersons is declared?

Comment: ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();

Comment: If that is you  arrayOfPersons, how are you differentiating First name and last name ?

Comment: Your `compareTo` method is `void`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Inside my persons class. Each persons object has it's own first name and last name.

Comment: Inside your if condition you are checking both `lname1` and `lname2` to your `Person` using && which can only be true when they are the same name.

Comment: your loop has a problem with it giving true only lname1 and lname2 are equal and also at the end, you can use if else instead of 4 if loops.

Comment: It's printing my warning message even though the contacts are being found and compared. I only wanted it to print in the event that the contacts were not found or the user entered in the names wrong due to the case sensitivity and the contacts were not found because of that. I don't want it to print my warning when the names are actually found and compared.

Comment: Also this line does nothing: `lname1.compareTo(lname2);`

Comment: try printing foundContact and check whether it comes true any time

Comment: @Eypros Yes, I see what you mean. I was trying to iterate through my array list and check to see if the two names entered by the user exist, but that's clearly the wrong logic. I need a way to scan through my entire array list by last name and check to see if an object exists in there with that last name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing like this ?

```
boolean foundlname1 = false,foundlname2 = false;

for(int i = 0;  i < arrayOfPersons.size(); i++)
{
    if(arrayOfPersons.get(i).getFname().equals(lname1) && !foundlname1)
         foundlanme1 = true;  
    if(arrayOfPersons.get(i).getFname().equals(lname2) && !foundlname2)
         foundlanme2 = true;     
     if(foundlanme1 && foundlanme2)
       {
          foundContact = true;
          break;   
       }
}

if (foundContact == false)
System.out.println("This option is case sensitive. Check your spelling and  try again. Otherwise these contacts do not exist.");

else if(lname1.compareToIgnoreCase(lname2) > 0)
System.out.println(lname1 + " comes after " + lname2 + " .");

else if(lname1.compareToIgnoreCase(lname2) == 0)
System.out.println(lname1 + " are equal " + lname2 + ".");

else
System.out.println(lname1 + " comes before " + lname2 + " .");

}
```

Comment: I tried. Has a logic error somewhere. This code doesn't compare the contacts even though they exist. I want the user of my address book to type in any name that's passed to the method as an argument. If those names the user typed exist in the arrayOfPersons then the method will compare them. If not, it does not compare them.

Comment: can you add Person class functions ?

Comment: I mean class definition of Person

Comment: I posted my persons class in an edit. Should be visible momentarily.

Comment: If you are trying to check for lname why are using getFname() ? and also try returning this.lname; @NickM

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement in the for loop will never be true unless lname1 and lname2 are equals. I don't know if what you did is what you wanted to do. You can do like this which is similar to your code you already have:

In the compareTo method check if the `arrayOfPersons` contains those two Persons

```
if(arrayOfPersons.contains(Person1) && arrayOfPersons.contains(Person2)
```

and then compare lname1 and lname2 like you did with your last three if statements

Note that to use the contains method you need to ovverride in your Person class the equals method

Comment: I want the person objects to already exist in the arrayOfPersons before comparing them. That is to say they exist in the address book. If they don't I want no comparison to happen. That is what I am trying to accomplish in my if statement. To check if they exist, and if they do let's compare them!

Comment: He is passing last names of 2 people, he is not sending Person object in the function. Your method can be done if he is passing object as the parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
public void compareTo(String lname1, String lname2) {      



 boolean foundContact1 = false;
 boolean foundContact2 = false;


for(int i = 0;  i < arrayOfPersons.size(); i++){
  if(arrayOfPersons.get(i).getLname().equals(lname1)) {
   foundContact1 = true; 
 }
}

for(int i = 0;  i < arrayOfPersons.size(); i++){
 if(arrayOfPersons.get(i).getLname().equals(lname2)) {
  foundContact2 = true; 
 }
}



if (foundContact1 && foundContact2 == false)
  System.out.println("This option is case sensitive. Check your spelling and try again. Otherwise these contacts do not exist.");

if(foundContact1 && foundContact2 == true) {

if(lname1.compareTo(lname2) < 0)
  System.out.println(lname1 + " comes after " + lname2 + " .");

else if(lname1.compareTo(lname2) == 0)
 System.out.println(lname1 + " are equal " + lname2 + ".");

else if(lname1.compareTo(lname2) > 0)
 System.out.println(lname1 + " comes before " + lname2 + " .");

 }

}
```

I figured it out. This is what I was looking for. Thanks for the pointers everybody. Similar to solution to what Shreshta proposed, just had to modify his logic a little bit.